# How can we minimize the below query?

Tags: entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities, query-performance

Below is the linq query which through an exception `Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.` What is the minimized query of below one,

```
return await base.Execute((dataContext) =>
            {
                var demo = (from proj in dataContext.ProjectStats
                            select new { a = proj } into sam
                            group sam by new
                            {
                                sam.a.ClassTypeID,
                                sam.a.StudentID
                            }
                 into gcs
                            select gcs.Select(x => new Dao.ProjectStat()
                            {
                                StudentID = gcs.Key.StudentID,
                                ClassTypeID = gcs.Key.ClassTypeID,
                                CompletedCount = gcs.Sum(y => y.a.CompletedCount),
                                FinishedTime = x.a.FinishedTime
                            })).SelectMany(g => g).SelectObject();
                return demo.ToList();
            });
```

Comment: Why the <sql> tag? (I see no SQL there...)

Comment: Which EF version is this and what is this `SelectObject` method?

Comment: EF version is 6.1.1 and `SelectObject` is used to convert database object into model.

Comment: Yeah, but what does it look like? That's probably the key to the answer. Maybe it triggers a lot of lazy loading.